# Pass a value to a hidden input when radio button clicked

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pass a value when a radio button clicked to a hidden input but it's not working, I tried to pass a value on a different page without using the output variable only a radio button with an already set value and it's passing it, but I don't know why the same code not working inside $output value.

This line should pass a price when the radio button is clicked.

```
<input type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById(checked_radio).value='.$row["o_price"].'" />
```

to this line inside valu=""

```
<input type="hidden" id="checked_radio" name="hidden_price" value="">
```

The full code is

```
    $limit = '20';
$page = 1;
if($_POST['page'] > 1)
{
  $start = (($_POST['page'] - 1) * $limit);
  $page = $_POST['page'];
}
else
{
  $start = 0;
}

$query = "
SELECT * FROM game
";

if($_POST['query'] != '')
{
  $query .= '
  WHERE game_name LIKE "%'.str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['query']).'%" 
  ';
}

$query .= 'ORDER BY id ASC ';

$filter_query = $query . 'LIMIT '.$start.', '.$limit.'';

$statement = $con->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$total_data = $statement->rowCount();

$statement = $con->prepare($filter_query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$total_filter_data = $statement->rowCount();

$output = '
<label>اجمالي الالعاب المتوفرة: '.$total_data.' لعبة</label>
<br />
';
if($total_data > 0)
{
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
    $output .= '
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&id='.$row["id"].'">
    <div class="game">
    <img src="images/'.$row["image"].'" class="img-responsive center-block" width="192" height="192" alt="'.$row["game_name"].'">
    <h5 class="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white" style="padding: 9px 1px 1px 1px; height: 40px;">'.$row["game_name"].'</h5>
    <h4 class="text-success">نوع المتجر: '.$row["store"].'</h4>
    

    <div class="radio">
    <label class="radio text-danger"><h5>
    سعر الأوفلاين: '.$row["o_price"].' ج.م المتوفر: '.$row["o_quantity"].'
    <input type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById(checked_radio).value='.$row["o_price"].'" />
    </label>
    </h5>
    </div>

    <h5 class="text-danger"> سعر البريماري: '.$row["p_price"].' ج.م المتوفر: '.$row["p_quantity"].'</h5>
    <h5 class="text-danger"> سعر السكندري: '.$row["s_price"].' ج.م المتوفر: '.$row["s_quantity"].'</h5>
    <h5 class="text-danger"> سعر الكامل: '.$row["f_price"].' ج.م المتوفر: '.$row["f_quantity"].'</h5>

    <h5 class="text-info"> مساحة اللعبة: '.$row["g_size"].' جيجا</h5>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="'.$row["game_name"].'">
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_store" value="'.$row["store"].'">
    <input type="hidden" id="checked_radio" name="hidden_price" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="add" style="margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-success"
    value="إضافة إلى القائمة">
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    ';
  }
}
else
{
  $output .= '
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">عذرا! لا يوجد بيانات لعرضها</td>
  </tr>
  ';
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to put the value into a hidden field to begin with, why don't you just let the radio button input itself send the value?

Comment: Because I have 4 different values I need to send one of them to the price list, Please check this [link](https://jadolyo.com/games/index.php)

Comment: _"Because I have 4 different values I need to send one of them to the price list"_ - that's what radio buttons already do. All you need to do is give _them_ `name="hidden_price"`, and remove the superfluous hidden field + script logic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`checked_radio` should be in string while accessing Element. Since you are concatenating in php you need to escape `\'checked_radio'\`

```
<input type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById(\'checked_radio\').value='.$row["o_price"].'" />
```

Or
You could set radio value by php and on click just pass current radio value like

```
<input type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById(\'checked_radio\').value=this.value" value='.$row["o_price"].' />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, both methods solved the quotation problem but they still not passing the value.

Comment: How you know its not passing value. Are you just checking by doing inspect? I see you are generating multiple forms by php forEach. So there will be multiple elements like `id="checked_radio"`. on your document.

Comment: Yes, I check by inspecting and by pressing submit so it should give me the price in a list, but the price is empty.

Comment: do you have multiple forms on same page? I see your forEach is generating `<form>` every row in result

Comment: Yes, I have multiple forms each form has its price value I should check one radio button and submit. [link](https://jadolyo.com/games/) it's games list.

Comment: That means you are creating multiple hidden fields with same `id="checked_radio"` id. There should be unique id for element throughout the html document

Comment: Yes, that's true, Should I use a different method?

Comment: Thank you for the hint I used `$id` as a variable inside the `id=""` and inside the `document.getElementById` and it's working now.

Comment: `<input type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById('.$row["id"].').value=this.value" value='.$row["o_price"].' />`
`<input type="hidden" id="'.$row["id"].'" name="hidden_price" value="">`

Thank you very much

Comment: Yes Yes this is was i was thinking to generate unique id. Or just i was coming up with iterate foreach with index like  `foreach($result as $key=>$value)`......`<input type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById(\'checked_radio'.$key.'\').value='.$row["o_price"].'" />` ....... `<input type="hidden" id="checked_radio'.$key.'" name="hidden_price">`..   Anyway your solution is also good.

Comment: Thank you, Your solution is good too, Have a nice day, Thanks for your great help.

Comment: Pleasure. Good day :)